# Problem with Autoincrement in SQL

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table like this

```
ID Name
1  RJ
2  Hello
3  NV 
4  Dere 
5  What
```

So when I am deleting the fourth entry from the database ( ID=4 and Name= dere ) by using this Sql Statement

```
Delete from Table where ID="4"
```

then it deletes the table row but when I see the table it looks to me as

```
ID Name
1  RJ
2  Hello
3  NV 
5  What
```

So is there any way that it also updates the auto increment ID automatically like I want the table to look like this as soon as I delete the table fourth entry

```
ID Name
1  RJ
2  Hello
3  NV 
4  What
```

Hope you have got to know my question..!!

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want that behaviour?

Comment: Don't renumber your primary key, that will just cause you a lot of trouble. (I can't find any other good use for autoincrement except creating primary keys)

Comment: Also, please post not only the business case/usage case/problem you are trying to solve, but also the specific platform.  Autonumber is not a general ANSI SQL concept and there are a number of SQL implementations.  We generally assume SQL Server if a person posts generally "SQL", but this can be very confusing to people here, because knowledgeable SQL users are familiar with several platforms and the differences therein.

Comment: ID is my primary key.. so that's why I wanted to be like that..!! So that ID should be in proper order...

Comment: @Raihan - you want your PK to change when you delete unrelated records?  Won't that break all your referential integrity?

Comment: @Raihan Jamal Why would you want a primary key to change value? Specifically an IDENTITY column which may have FK related to it. Generally when we use an IDENTITY as a PK and also cluster on it, because we like our clustering keys unique, static, narrow and increasing, we don't change primary keys, not only because of FKs which might refer to it, but because you don't want to re-arrange data pages.  Note that an IDENTITY does not need to be a PK or be clustered, but they do often go together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This would involve updating potentially hundreds of thousands of records. Your code shouldn't require that keys be contiguous. You should never assume anything about the keys.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept. Yes you are right... I got confused... Really Appreciated.!!

Answer (score 4):

That's not what IDENTITY/autonumber columns are for.

If you need a dynamic column number (based on what order?), use something dynamic, not a plain old data column.

For example, you could just get rid of that ID column and add a datetime column on CreationDate defaulting to GETDATE()

```
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreationDate) AS ID
FROM tbl
```

Comment: Somehow it seems like your default RDBMS is SQL Server. :)

Comment: @Andriy M It is.  Although I spend more time in Oracle these days.  One problem with SQL Server being so accessible and popular with newbies is they tend to abbreviate it to SQL, especially here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did encounter such people here. Haven't noticed it to be a tendency so far, but will pay more attention in future. Thanks for sharing your observation.

Answer (score 1):

declare @id int
set @id = 4
Delete from Table where ID=@id

Update Table
Set ID = ID - 1
WHERE ID > @ID

**BUT DON'T DO THIS**

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept. Yes you are right... I got confused... Really Appreciated.!!

Answer (score 1):

Forgive this, but why? It's just a number, and down the road is is likely you will have other tables that refer to this one by the ID. That's what DB's do best. Don't worry about the numbering.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept. Yes you are right... I got confused... Really Appreciated.!!

Answer (score 0):

it is common sql behavior for Identity.

Comment: Note that an IDENTITY column does not have to be the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: It often is a PK and clustered also, just wanted to point out that it doesn't have to be.  You are correct that the gap behavior is consistent and necessary - also happens with even simple aborted transactions where an identity is "used up".

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept. Yes you are right... I got confused... Really Appreciated.!!